# Magento 2: ACL Permission for Admin Module

Tags: magento2, admin, custom, user-roles, acl

I have multiple Admin User Roles with Users.

For my Custom Module it's not giving "Access denied" for non - authorized Admin.

I have followed

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-acl-access-control-lists.html

Able to hide menu from Admin, but can access from URL

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\adminhtml\system.xml**

```
<resource>Custom_Module::configuration</resource>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Custom_Module::Module" title="Module" sortOrder="10" >
                    <resource id="Custom_Module::posts" title="Module Posts" sortOrder="10">
                        <resource id="Custom_Module::posts_save" title="Save Post" sortOrder="10" />
                        <resource id="Custom_Module::posts_delete" title="Delete Post" sortOrder="20" />
                    </resource>
                    <resource id="Custom_Module::messages" title="Module Messages" sortOrder="10" >
                        <resource id="Custom_Module::messages_save" title="Save Message" sortOrder="10" />
                        <resource id="Custom_Module::messages_delete" title="Delete Message" sortOrder="20" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Custom_Module::configuration" title="Configuration" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Custom_Module::Module" module="Custom_Module" resource="Custom_Module::Module" sortOrder="11" title="Module"/>
        <add action="custom_module/posts/index" id="Custom_Module::posts" module="Custom_Module" parent="Custom_Module::Module" resource="Custom_Module::posts" sortOrder="1" title="Posts"/>
        <add action="custom_module/messages/index" id="Custom_Module::messages" module="Custom_Module" parent="Custom_Module::Module" resource="Custom_Module::messages" sortOrder="2" title="Messages"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\Index.php**

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Custom_Module::posts');
}
```

While Edit Posts/Messages it's giving Access Denied. But for Both Listing it's not giving same kind of Error.

Answer (score 0):

It create an issue because you have define `ACL` for `system configuration` not for your `controller` `action`, for that you have to define your module `controller` action `ACL`, like I am assuming your link example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
     <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Mageplaza_HelloWorld::helloworld" title="Hello World" sortOrder="51">
                    <resource id="Mageplaza_HelloWorld::post" title="Posts" sortOrder="10"/>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Still not working :( Still able to open URL & Access on restricted user account

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: I am looking set ACL for admin users view another store details like sales, orders how to add my condition in https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-acl-access-control-lists.html  Any help thanks post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/322871/57334