# Magento 2: ACL Permission Call Manually for Logged In Admin

Tags: admin, custom, controllers, acl, magento-2.1.3

[Magento 2: ACL Permission for Admin Module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150194/magento-2-acl-permission-for-admin-module)

In

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\Index.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $this->_isAllowed();

        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Posts'));

        return $resultPage;
    }

    /*
     * Check permission via ACL resource
     */

    public function _isAllowed() {
        return $this->_authorization->->isAllowed('Custom_Module::posts');
    }
}
```

While calling this it's giving error

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property:
>   Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\Index\Interceptor::$_authorization
>   in
>   D:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Posts\Index.php
>   on line 55

Why i'm doing manually, because my Module Permission is still not working. So for Authrization we have `module-authorization` Module. Would like to use that Manually in Controller/Block file. Ideal Controller.

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager
$aclObject  = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl');
```

If i use above then it gives `Class 'Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl' not found`

Comment: Hi @fschmengler updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller does not extend `Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction`, where `_authorization` is defined. In a non-admin controller you are not supposed to use the ACL.

About the second part of your question: I am not sure what exactly you want to do with `$aclObject`, but there really is no class `Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl` in Magento. Did you mean `Magento\Framework\Acl` ?

Comment: Yes. So instead of `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` need to use `Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction` then all works fine?

Comment: Theoretically yes. But I also saw your other question and could not find out what's wrong. Good luck!